# Notations used to express direction

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, vectors, conventions, coordinate-systems

We express direction relative to a reference point and call a certain direction positive and it's direct opposite direction negative, by convention. 
But, what notation should we use to express a direction in between the two opposite directions? 
I might be overthinking this. Can you help me out.

Comment: Consider rewording the question, it is unclear what you mean by "a direction in between". If you mean in between on a polar coordinate system, then any direction in between say $0$ and $\pi$, is just a another angle in polar, and in Cartesian it will have two components: one parallel and one perpendicular with respect to the "opposite directions".

Comment: I couldn't make sense of your question first, but now it appears to me that you are asking about a scalar or dot product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between two vectors. The scalar product is, as the name says, a scalar and given by the product of the two lengths of the vectors times the cosine of the angle between them. For parallel unit vectors this is 1, for anti-parallel unit vectors the scalar product is -1 and for orthogonal vectors it's 0.

Comment: Should be $c\vec V$ where $c$ is anywhere in between -1 and 1.